# T_SQL Function with Column Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, parameters

I built a sql function which takes some values from my table

### [image: Table Schema]

Such as DS_Consultor, No_Periodo and No_HORAS_REG to use on a function that calculates the total hours per month of every single worker and then calculates the work percentage of every single entry with this function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CAL]
(
    @EMP NVARCHAR(70),
    @PER NVARCHAR(50),
    @HORAS DECIMAL(18,1)
)
RETURNS @RES TABLE 
(   
    RES DECIMAL(18, 1)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TEMPTABLE TABLE
(
    DS_CONSULTOR NVARCHAR(70),
    NO_PERIODO NVARCHAR(50),
    RECUENTO DECIMAL(18,1)
)

INSERT @tempTable
SELECT OC.DS_CONSULTOR, OC.NO_PERIODO, SUM(OC.NO_HORAS_REG) AS RECUENTO
FROM Occupation OC
GROUP BY OC.DS_CONSULTOR, OC.NO_PERIODO

INSERT  @RES
    SELECT @HORAS/T1.RECUENTO AS RES
    FROM @tempTable T1
    WHERE T1.DS_CONSULTOR=@EMP AND T1.NO_PERIODO=@HORAS

   RETURN
END
```

However I can't add the column paramters that i need for a calculated column

```
SELECT cal.RES
FROM Occupation OC
CROSS APPLY CAL(DS_CONSULTOR, NO_PERIODO, NO_HORAS_REG)--This outputs 'Error 
converting data type nvarchar to numeric.'
```

Is there something worng with the parameters or is it the function inpu/output?

Comment: well, `NO_PERIODO` is defined as `nvarchar` in the table, but `@HORAS` is a `decimal`

Comment: They are different parameters, NO_PERIODO is used to filter the results of the main query, @HORAS is used to calculate the relative time

DS_CONSULTOR = '@EMP'
NO_PERIODO = '@PER'
NO_HORAS_REG = '@HORAS'

Comment: but you are using `T1.NO_PERIODO=@HORAS`, one is a `nvarchar` and the other is a `decimal`, which is where I assume you are getting your error

Comment: When you write table valued functions you should make them a single statement instead of multiple statements. The performance difference is HUGE. What you have is a multi-statement table valued function and the performance is often even worse than scalar functions.

Comment: I havent noticed that mistake
My bad
THank you

Comment: @SeanLange it's there in the code: `'Error 
converting data type nvarchar to numeric.'`

Comment: @Lamak - so it is. I just saw the "This outputs error" and skipped the next line. >.<